# Android application not working on 1.5 firmware?

Tags: android, android-activity

i have created a single page application of showing phonebook data in a list.
i am using 2.1 sdk in emulator and application works fine.

but in my HTC hero firmware is 1.5 when i try to intall same application on HTC hero
application is installed successfully but when i click on app icon it gives me force close error even i have set minsdkversion property in manifest file to 3 here is the log Cat

```
[2010-05-17 12:28:18 - AddressBook]Starting activity com.example.AddressBook.AddressBook on device 
[2010-05-17 12:28:19 - AddressBook]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-05-17 12:28:19 - AddressBook]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
[2010-05-17 12:28:20 - AddressBook]ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { comp={com.example.AddressBook/com.example.AddressBook.AddressBook} }
```

please help me out whats wrong?
any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.1 and 1.5 use different Content Providers. 2.1 uses android.provider.ContactsContract
and 1.5 uses android.provider.Contacts. I guess you might be using the 2.1 provider which does not exists for 1.5

Comment: then what is the solution for both?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368898/how-do-i-use-the-features-of-2-01-yet-still-support-1-5-with-one-apk